# Why do double hung windows have sash stops

Tags: windows

Double hung windows have a sash stop to keep then from opening all the way by a few inches. The only reason I can figure they are used is to make the window operation foolproof. Without it, when Clement Clarke Moore throws open the sash on Christmas Eve, the window could get stuck open.  Is there some other practical purpose? Google isn't helpful at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a safety feature.

When the bottom sash is opened (or can be opened) wider than a few inches (4” is max.) then a small child can climb/fall out.

This feature is especially important on second / third floor windows.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, double-hung window sashes are *removed* by opening them to the limit of their travel, then pulling the sash away from the frame (after removing sash stop and molding). This movement to the limit also usually reveals parts of whatever balance and attachment mechanism(s) the window is equipped with. "They" don't want the end user to extend the window that far; except deliberately, to effect repairs.